# How to send data from Aura Components to Google Tag Manager?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, experience-builder-page, google-analytics, tag-manager

I'm trying to implement GTM in Experience builder. But I want to send the send some page details through datalayer to GTM. I couldn't find right documents & articles for that. Can Anyon help me with this?

Thanks in advance.